# Linux/Windows: User mode vs Privilege mode time spent

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

How much percentage of time CPU spends in user mode vs privilege mode for different programs/operations.
Different Operations could be:
- running application without I/O interaction.
- application with I/O interaction like copying a file to USB

I know for a fact that Network operating system spends most of the time in interrupt context. Does this hold true for general purpose OS like Ubuntu/Windows?

Comment: Look at the `time` command on Linux. The user column is time spent in userspace, and the system column is for time spent in kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not much of an OS expert but I imagine it will depend a great deal on what background processes are running on the system.  On any OS you might or might not be running some system (i.e. non-user) processes that are heavy resource users.  Or you might have put some effort into stripping the system down so that very little CPU time is being used by the system for background maintenance.

If your question is how things compare for "clean" installations of these operating systems then all I can tell you is that on my laptop running Ubuntu right now (running `top` from the command line to look at resource usage) only about 5-10% of CPU time is being used by non-user processes; in my case Xorg and compiz are the main ones.  I don't really know how that compares to Windows, but I think most linux users have a knee jerk reaction that Windows is greedier for system resources than most linux distros.

So, I guess the short answer is that I doubt there is a short answer to your question.